# SVN same setup, same user, fine from one machine but from another DAV/PROPFIND error

Tags: apache, svn

I have an SVN server that's been running for a few years now, with no issues. I've got a new user who just needed access so I created him a username and put him in my group with rw privaleges.

I've used his un/pass to check out the repo, so I know it's not a permissions issue.

When he goes in a browser, it all works fine and he can login and see the repo. But when he uses a terminal or an SVN client interface, he gets various errors when he tries to connect.

Cornerstone (new download) said "...domain/svn/repo does not support the HTTP/DAV protocol".

Using a terminal, it said "svn: E175004: The PROPFIND response did not include the requested resourcetype value"

I'm baffled because he has the same computer setup as me, and is just trying to check out the repo. Me and the other user who used to be in there have never had an issue. I am able to do all the things w/his user that we need him to do, but he cannot do them. He is not on any VPN or firewall or anything weird like that. I even hopped on my VPN to see if a new IP would throw it, but I was also able to check out fine.

I also had him try the direct IP vs the domain. Again, worked great for me and same errors for him.

Any thoughts? This is driving me crazy. Thanks in advance!